# excel object that cannot be edited

Tags: excel, formulas

I have the following Excel file:

[image: See the following Excel file.]

It has some inserted boxes in column `B`. I can fill in those boxes with numbers, but I cannot use them for my further calculations (in formulas). Also, right-click or any <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> functions don't work with those boxes.

Does anyone know how to use those numbers in the consequent formulas?
E.g. `C4=B4*0.3`

Comment: Do you need the textboxes for anything? Why not just delete them and use the sheet "as it was supposed to"? I don't think you can add formulas in textboxes

Comment: The linked cell property of the control has to be assigned and used instead. The value of the text box cannot be used directly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your cells have wrong format.

To use number values from the cells you need to set their format as **Number**. To do it select the cells you want modify, right click and choose it from the list:

[image]

Comment: She says in the question that she has inserted textboxes on the sheet, and that she can not use formulas in the textboxes.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see it in the question. Anyway let her clarify a bit of what is she trying to do?

Comment: "it has some inserted boxes", If you click on insert the only option I know of on the ribbon that is a "box" is the textbox.

Comment: thanks @Andreas that's interesting, I didn't know that. Anyway let the question asker clarify it, so that we don't guess what did she mean.